# How can I change the environment of my bash function without affecting the environment it was called from?

Tags: bash, function, environment

I am working on a bash script that needs to operate on several directories. In each directory it needs to source a setup script unique to that directory and then run some commands. I need the environment set up when that script is sourced to only persist inside the function, as if it had been called as an external script with no persistent effects on the calling script.

As a simplified example if I have this script, sourced.sh:

```
export foo=old
```

And I have this as my driver.sh:

```
export foo=young
echo $foo
source_and_run(){ 
    source ./sourced.sh 
    echo $foo 
}
source_and_run
echo $foo
```

I want to know how to change the invocation of source_and_run in driver so it will print:

```
young
old
young
```

I need to be able to collect the return value from the function as well. I'm pretty sure there's a simple way to accomplish this but I haven't been able to track it down so far.

Creating another script like external.sh:

```
source ./sourced.sh; echo $foo
```

and defining source_and_run like

```
source_and_run(){ ./external.sh; return $? }
```

would work but managing that extra layer of scripts seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `return $?` at the end of the function is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> Creating another script like external.sh:
>
> ```
> source ./sourced.sh; echo $foo
> ```
>
> and defining source_and_run like
>
> ```
> source_and_run(){ ./external.sh; return $? }
> ```
>
> would work but managing that extra layer of scripts seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

You can get the same behavior by using a subshell. Note the `()` instead of `{}`.

But note that `return $?` is not necessary in your case. By default, a function returns the exit status of its last command. In your case, that command is `echo`. Therefore, the return value will always be `0`.

```
source_and_run() (
    source ./sourced.sh
    echo "$foo"
)
```

By the way: A better solution would be to rewrite `sourced.sh` such that it prints `$foo`. That way you could call the script directly instead of having to source it and then using `echo $foo`.

Comment: The return value doesn't matter and the activity in 'sourced' is trivial in this simple example but my actual application has different return codes depending on the outcome of different operations, and the 'real' sourced script is complex enough to want to keep it separate. But subshells were the correct answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The very purpose of a bash *function* is that it runs in the same process as the invoker.

Since the environment is accessible (for instance, using the command `printenv`),you could, at the entry of the function, save the environment and at the end restore it. However, the easier and more natural approach is to not use a function at all, but make it a separate shell script which is executed ín its own process and hence has its own environment, which does not affect the environment of the caller anymore.